# How to use RestTemplate efficiently with RequestFactory?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, resttemplate

I am working on a project in which I need to make a HTTP URL call to my server which is running Restful Service which returns back the response as a JSON String. I am using `RestTemplate` here along with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` to execute an url.

I have setup a http request timeout (READ and CONNECTION time out) on my `RestTemplate` by using `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

Below is my Interface:

```
public interface Client {

    // for synchronous
    public String getSyncData(String key, long timeout);

    // for asynchronous
    public String getAsyncData(String key, long timeout);
}
```

Below is my implementation of Client interface -

```
public class DataClient implements Client {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    // for synchronous call
    @Override
    public String getSyncData(String key, long timeout) {
        String response = null;

        try {
            Task task = new Task(key, restTemplate, timeout);

            // direct call, implementing sync call as async + waiting is bad idea. 
            // It is meaningless and consumes one thread from the thread pool per a call.               
            response = task.call();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
        }

        return response;
    }

    // for asynchronous call
    @Override
    public Future<String> getAsyncData(String key, long timeout) {
        Future<String> future = null;

        try {
            Task task = new Task(key, restTemplate, timeout);
            future = executor.submit(task); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            PotoLogging.logErrors(ex, DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_ERROR, key);
        }

        return future;
    }
}
```

And below is my simple Task class

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String key;
    private long timeout; // in milliseconds

    public Task(String key, RestTemplate restTemplate, long timeout) {
        this.key = key;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        String url = "some_url_created_by_using_key";

        // does this looks right the way I am setting request factory?
        // or is there any other effficient way to do this?
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory());
        String response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);

        return response;
    }

    private static ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
        // is it ok to create a new instance of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory everytime?
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setReadTimeout(timeout); // setting timeout as read timeout
        factory.setConnectTimeout(timeout); // setting timeout as connect timeout
        return factory;
    }   
}
```

Now my question is - Does the way I am using `RestTemplate` along with `setRequestFactory` in the call method of Task class everytime is efficient? Since `RestTemplate` is very heavy to be created so not sure whether I got it right.

And is it ok to create a new instance of `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` everytime? Will it be expensive?

What is the right and efficient way to use `RestTemplate` if we need to setup Read and Connection timeout on it.

This library will be used like this -

```
String response = DataClientFactory.getInstance().getSyncData(keyData, 100);
```

Comment: FYI There is an AsyncRestTemplate spring 4.

Comment: @AdamGent I see, will it be useful in my scenario?

Comment: The AsyncRestTemplate could potentially remove the need for the Task entirely, as it returns a `Future`. Instead of choosing between executing a task directly or submitting it to an executor, you can just choose to run the request on a normal RestTemplate or an Async one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're reusing the same `RestTemplate` object repeatedly, but each `Task` is performing this line: `restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory());`. This seems like it can have race conditions, e.g. one `Task` can set the `RequestFactory` that another `Task` will then accidentally use.

Otherwise, it seems like you're using `RestTemplate` correctly.

How often do your timeouts change? If you mostly use one or two timeouts, you can create one or two `RestTemplate`s using the `RequestFactory` constructor with the pre-loaded timeout. If you're a stickler for efficiency, create a `HashMap<Integer, RestTemplate>` that caches a `RestTemplate` with a particular timeout each time a new timeout is requested.

Otherwise, looking at the code for [RestTemplate's constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java#L145), and for [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory's constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java#L80), they don't look exceptionally heavy, so calling them repeatedly probably won't be much of a bottleneck.

Comment: I can see that race conditions what you explained just now after closely looking at the code. How can I avoid that race condition?

Comment: Each customer will use this library in their code base, so they will only have one timeout set always, they will not keep on changing timeout values for each call. Once it is set, it will be used for all the calls they will make to this library.

Comment: The easy way to fix the race condition is to create a new RestTemplate just before creating the Task. Then you don't need to pass the timeout to the Task at all. If one library usage only has one timeout set, I'd suggest adding DataClient.setTimeout(int timeout). Then you could use one RestTemplate, set the timeout once through that function, and move on with life.

Comment: Can you provide an example how can I do that? This will help me to understand better.

Comment: Example of which? To avoid the race condition, move "clientHttpRequestFactory" from Task into DataClient. Then the Task creation line will just look like "Task task = new Task(key, new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory(timeout));"

Comment: To implement the "one RestTemplate", create a setTimeout(int timeout) on DataClient. The method would just look like "restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory(timeout))". I think you'll be able to take the rest from here.